# Closing workbook with partial file name

Tags: excel, vba, filepath, partial

I have vba that works great to open a file based of a partial criteria met. but when I have multiple files open the file opening by the below VBA remains open when done and I am having trouble how to call that workbook back to close it seeing it opens off partial parameters being met. in quick summary the opencopy (opens a file), then in another vba I copy that data, and pastes it into another workbook (done in another VBA) when done i want to bring that workbook back up and just close it. if i do activeworkbook.close it closes the workbook i'm working on which i don't want. Help im stuck!

```
Sub OpenCopy()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sPartial As String
Dim sFName As String

sPath = "C:\" ' <<<<< change accordingly

sPartial = "AAA_" & Year(Now) & IIf(Len(Month(Now)) = 1, "0" & Month(Now), Month(Now)) & 
IIf(Len(Day(Now)) = 1, "0" & Day(Now), Day(Now)) & "*.txt"
sFName = Dir(sPath & sPartial)
If Len(sFName) > 0 Then
Workbooks.OpenText sPath & sFName
Else
MsgBox "File not found.", vbExclamationEnd If
End Sub
```

Comment: Make `OpenCopy` a function, and have it return the name of the file it opened, or maybe a reference to the open workbook.  The calling code can then use that to close the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in "the other VBA". Try to force your project to comply with the rules by which VBA works.

That would mean to acknowledge that there is only one VBA. That VBA has procedures. You can call these procedures manually (which you probably do, and which leads you to talk of "the other VBA") or you can create a *Main* procedure that calls them for you, one after the other. The advantage of this would be that you can declare objects and variables in the *Main* which could be made available to all procedures, passed as arguments.

So, you would open a file, finding it by an abbreviated description of its name. You would assign this file to a variable, say `File1`, and now you could refer to it from anywhere in your project to read or copy from and to close it. You never need to know its name because you refer to it by the variable name to which it was assigned. VBA will assure that the name is unique.

As an alternative, you could of course take the file's complete name from the file after it was opened and then close the file by its complete name. In fact, the `Dir` function in your code does provide the complete name. So you could take it from there even before the file is opened. As I said, the problem is that the name would be in "the other VBA", an idea that isn't supported by VBA.

But, presuming that you want to continue with your piecemeal approach at least for the moment, wouldn't you be able to identify the file by the same partial details that led you to find it in the first place? I presume that the names of files you have open at the same time would differ in the "AAA" part. So, `If Instr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, "AAA") = 1 Then` would identify a file. You could loop through all open workbooks with `For Each Wb In Application.Workbooks` and check each name. You may have to add an input box to enter "AAA" another time because your different "VBAs" can't be made to talk to each other.

By the way, your beautiful partial string could be simplified using VBA's `Format` function. Try this.

`sPartial = "AAA_" & format(date, "yyyymmdd")`

Comment: Not a fan of my approach ended up just using Workbooks(2).Close Savechanges:=False which gets me there. I cant take credit for the partial file code I got help from a friend to bring it all together. So wasnt sure how to modify that existing code to now just close the workbook

Comment: `Workbooks(2).Close` closes the second workbook in the queue. The most recently one opened is #1. Therefore `Workbooks(2).Close`  will crash if there is only one workbook open at the time and it will close the wrong file if the one you want to close wasn't the next to last one to have been opened.

Comment: Yeah see that is my fear. the whole vba will open a file that brings data all together, then opens a 2nd wb the above one copy the data paste it into wkb 1, then just need wkb 2 to close then proceed on its way if that makes sense :)

Comment: At this point of your code you have everything: `Workbooks.OpenText sPath & sFName`You have the complete file name. And you could create an object variable with `Set Wb = Workbooks.OpenText(sPath & sFName)`. But both chances are lost due to your code structure. If you would post all of your code we could probably fit it together in a way that it can do what you want.